# How to map values to a colorbar to customize bar chart colors

Tags: python, matplotlib, normalization, colormap

I would like to customize the bar colors of a bar chart depending on some criteria. The color value should be taken from a built-in python colormap "seismic" red -> white -> blue. I cannot do it (the values I set do not map correctly to the colormap colors)
example : 
- if I set 0 I would like the darkest blue => I do not have it
- if I set 1 I would like the darkest red => I do not have it
- if I set a value between 0 and 1, I would like the color in this range from the colormap 'seismic' => but if I set 0.34, the color picked up is 0.39...

I have tried different pieces of codes found here and there but none has helped so far

```
# bar color list
bar_color = []

for x in y_val:
    # I would like to assign the most red color of my color bar so "1"!
    if y_line_val > y_val[count] + yerr[count]:
        bar_color.append(1)
    # I would like to assign the most blue color of my color bar so "0"!
    elif y_line_val < y_val[count] - yerr[count]:
         bar_color.append(0)
    # I pick up a color between [0,1] => 0.34 in this example
    else:
        bar_color.append(yerr[count]/yerr_max)
    count += 1

my_cmap = cm.get_cmap('seismic')
print(my_cmap)
#<matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap object at 0x7efea9b3b748>
colors = my_cmap(bar_color)
print(colors)
#[[ 0.5         0.          0.          1.        ] => why not 1
# [ 0.5         0.          0.          1.        ] => why not 1
# [ 0.5         0.          0.          1.        ] => why not 1
# [ 0.39607843  0.39607843  1.          1.        ]] => why not 0.34
norm = mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=0, vmax=1)
m = cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=my_cmap, norm=norm)

m.set_array([])

cbar = plt.colorbar(m)
cbar.set_label('Chance of being lower than the line', rotation=270, labelpad=25)

#creation color bar
bar = ax.bar(ind, y_val, yerr=yerr, align='center', alpha=0.5, edgecolor='black', linewidth=2, ecolor='black', capsize=10, color=colors)

plt.show()
```

See in the code the values for the colors I get against what I expected.
I am sure I am missing something in between for the mapping...

I do not want to use a solution looping on the bars and setting a facecolor depending on some criteria... instead, I would like to use a solution with a colormap.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Could you please format your code to be a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), following the guidelines ?

Comment: `0` selects the first color, `1` selects the second color. Use float values, `1.0` and `0.0` respectively. The value for `yerr[count]/yerr_max` should be correct.

Comment: Thanks, trying with 1.0 and 0.0 did not work either. I get the same output. The colours are not correct!